# Jaeger standalone without docker

Tags: jaeger

Cannot find any information if Jaeger can be executed without docker?
Does a standalone jar exist, or will there be a release in the future for Jaeger like Zipkin has ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Downloads page (https://www.jaegertracing.io/download/) lists both the Docker images and the raw binaries built for various platforms (Linux, macOS, windows). You can also build binaries from source.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Yuris answer, you can also download the source from github - [Github - Jaeger](https://test) This is useful for diagnosing issues, or just getting a better understanding of how it all works.

I have run both the released apps and custom versions on both windows and linux servers without issues. For windows I would recommend running as a service using Nssm. [Nssm details](https://nssm.cc/usage)